# cannot telnet into ubuntu from windows 7

Tags: networking, server, firewall, port-forwarding, telnet

I have a php server running on port 4444 on my Ubuntu 15.04 machine. Now when I execute `telnet 127.0.0.1 4444` it works fine. Now I have connected my machine and a windows 7 machine using mobile hotspot. I got my ip address using `ifconfig` which shows

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b4:b6:76:b2:18:b7  
      inet addr:192.168.43.115  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::b6b6:76ff:feb2:18b7/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:23468 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:21537 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:15077925 (15.0 MB)  TX bytes:3582649 (3.5 MB)
```

Now when I execute `telnet 192.168.43.115 4444` on my windows machine i get `Could not open connection to the host, on port 4444: Connect Failed`. `nmap -sU 127.0.0.1 -p 4444` shows the following

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-22 23:03 IST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00015s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
4444/udp closed krb524
```

And `netstat -tulpn` shows the following

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address       State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4444          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1611/php        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21107           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           1744/chromium-brows
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34051           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp6       0      0 :::56100                :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::25246                :::*                                -               
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -
```

How can I fix this? Please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to use telnet, but instead to use SSH.  The reason for this, is that telnet communications are unencrypted, and vulnerable to eavesdropping.

You can make your PHP server allow remote connections via SSH by installing openssh-server:

> > sudo apt-get install openssh-server

If you still want to use telnet, then according to your output, it would appear that port 4444 is not open on you Linux box.  Assuming you've not setup a firewall on that computer, it would appear that your server is not running the telnet server.  To install that service:

> > sudo apt-get install telnetd

I hope this helps.

Comment: I installed telnet and ssh. Still when i try to telnet into port 4444 it says the same failed message. However when I ssh into port 22 it logs in perfectly and gives me root access to ubuntu terminal. can I ssh into port 4444. if yes then how?

Comment: You can ssh into port 4444, if you change /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the server.  Why does the server need to listen on port 4444?

Comment: Because I wrote the program to listen on port 4444. What else can i do?

Comment: If you only need the program to run upon remote login, you could rewrite your program to listen to port 22.

Otherwise, what is the benefit of having the program listen to port 4444?

Answer (score 0):

In your `netstat` output, the line

> `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4444          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1611/php`

Indicates that php (process id 1611) is listening on **TCP** port 4444 on the **internal** address 127.0.0.1.  That's on the loop-back interface, and can only be reached from the local host, your Ubuntu machine, not from the Windows box.

In contrast, e.g., your chromium-brows... (PID 1744) listens on `0.0.0.0`, which is special, meaning "all interfaces" (so it should be reachable from the outside, e.g., the Windows machine).

Your nmap UDP probe reports the port "closed" because php uses the TCP protocol.

I find `lsof` useful for investigating what's listening, but .  To get some output on my machine, I'll ask for port 22 (SSH) instead of 4444:

> $ sudo lsof -P -i :22  
>   `COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
>   sshd    2152 root    5u  IPv4  10192      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
>   sshd    2152 root    6u  IPv6  10194      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)`

You see it listens on "*" (all interfaces).  As in your case, a UDP scan won't find it open:

> $ sudo nmap -sU 127.0.0.1 -p 22
>    
>   `Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-22 13:53 EST
>   Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
>   Host is up (0.000048s latency).
>   PORT   STATE  SERVICE
>   22/udp closed ssh`
>    
>   `Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.37 seconds`

So much for the explanation of what you saw.  To fix, you should instruct your PHP server to listen on 0.0.0.0 or * instead of 127.0.0.1 or "localhost".  I don't know that program; if you cannot change its configuration, you could always use `ssh` or `iptables` to forward the port.

/Quigi

Comment: I have added rules to the iptable to allow incoming connection on port 4444 using `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4444 -j ACCEPT` and also `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 4444 -j ACCEPT` just to be sure.